# product table mapping to transactions

Tags: mysql, database

I am designing a database and want to know: what is the best way to map a transaction to multiple products? E.g. if customer buys product x, y, z all in one transaction (transaction id 123). What is the best way to link the transaction to the table of products?

I was also considering using a way to store array of all items selected (products) in the transaction table, but then that would make it difficult to retrieve prices for each product later when processing.

In need for your experience

Thanks

Comment: why not the product_id. you could have a transactions table with 1 line per trans# then have a transdetail table with multiple rows for that trans with a product_id column that could join u back to products

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following model should suit your needs:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tTransaction`;
CREATE TABLE `tTransaction` (
    `transactionId`     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `transactionAmount` NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
    /* Other Data */
    PRIMARY KEY (`transactionId`)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tProduct`;
CREATE TABLE `tProduct` (
    `productId`   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `productName` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    /* Other Data */
    PRIMARY KEY (`productId`)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tTransactionProductMap`;
CREATE TABLE `tTransactionProductMap` (
    `transactionId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `productId`     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactionId`) REFERENCES tTransaction (`transactionId`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`productId`) REFERENCES tProduct (`productId`)
);
```